# Cron job failed using CodeIgniter in Google Appengine

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, cron

Using PHP framework in Google App Engine, Cron job failed when I using the index.php url with `login:required`. I used `login:admin` for cron.

Refer my app.yaml file

```
app.yaml

application: my-app
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1


- url: /.*
  script: index.php
  login: required

- url: /backup_cron/remindermail
  static_dir: backup_cron/remindermail
  login: admin
```

I don't want use `no login` and `login: admin` to my index.php load.

My app can see all those who has Gmail login only. With no login cron job worked fine.

Is it possible with login:required used in first loading page?

With `login:required`

log details:

> HTTP/1.1" 302
>
> > Request failed because URL requires user login. For requests invoked
> >     within App Engine (offline requests like Task Queue, or webhooks like
> >     XMPP and Incoming Mail), the URL must require admin login (or no
> >     login).

With `no login`nd `login:admin`

Log details:

> HTTP/1.1" 200
>
> Success

Comment: Did you test cron on `index.php` without login at all? Or with `login: admin`? Also, what do the logs say?

Comment: Thank for you reply MeLight. I updated log details in the post.Plz review

Comment: It fails to run the cron job when login is set to 'login:admin'?

Comment: sry, Login success when login is set to 'login:admin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crons can not access url's protected by `login: required` because they are not ran as users. 
From docs:

> Note: While cron jobs can use URL paths restricted with login: admin, they cannot use URL paths restricted with login: required because cron scheduled tasks are not run as any user. The admin restriction is satisfied by the inclusion of the X-Appengine-Cron header described below.

Link here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Securing_URLs_for_cron

That being said, I suggest you use a specific handler for all your protected jobs. Or you could redirect non-logged in users.